# MoxieManager mc_access file not overwriting config options

Tags: php, config

I am using moxiemanager for some image work for a website I am working on and in my config.php I have read and write access for the filesystem set to false for security reasons. Then in any folder that needs read or write permission I want to use the mc_access file to set those permissions. So the settings look like so:

```
$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.readable'] = false;
$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.writable'] = false;
```

Then in the mc_access I have it set like so:

```
_filesystem.writable=true
_filesystem.readable=true
```

I have other settings in there that are pulled from the mc_config file (upload.maxsize), and I am following the format given by the docs at moxiemanager.com. In addition if I set the permissions in reverse (the config.php has them true and the mc_access has them false) the mc_access file configurations stick. But when it is set up as I have above the mc_access settings do not stick and the folders remain unwritable and unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was  bug in the moxie manager software. I contacted their support team and they patched the issue in November

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a hard one, but as I can figure out setting **filesystem.readable** to **false** in the **config.php** will prevent reading anything in the filesystem, **including those mc_access files**. The solution is most lightly to **do it in reverse** as you mentioned, by setting filesystem.readable to true - and then use mc_access in your various sensitive folders to make them not readable. MoxieManager is poorly documented and tutorials are none-existent, so you need to try this out the hard way.